# Should I leave main water off after my back flow preventer broke?

Tags: plumbing, water, freezing, backflow-preventer

Due to unusually cold temps my back flow preventer (Febco 765-1) has frozen and broken. I was under the impression that my back flow preventer in my backyard was only relevant to my sprinkler system, but I'm not really sure.

Does this affect my main water line/is my main water supply all potentially contaminated now?

Comment: Is there a closed valve isolating the backflow preventer from your home's water lines?

Comment: I don't believe so? I've simply shut off both the home's water and the valves on the backflow preventer itself. If I turn the water back on then the backflow preventer won't leak.

Comment: So you live in a mild climate where winterizing an irrigation system is typically unnecessary? Unusual freezing blew up your backflow preventer? And now you're worried about contamination of your water supply? I think that you're crazy to worry, but I've never seen a pattern resulting in irrigation water coming back into the home. I've heard of interfacing a septic tank with an irrigation system somehow, but a whole city with backflow preventers when everybody's on sewer doesn't make sense. Maybe diffusion, but I don't know how contaminated water would get behind the valves.

Comment: typically winterize annually this time of year. This kind of freezing has unfortunately been usual in Texas for the past 3-4 years, but this was the first time my backflow preventer actually burst. I had the same logic as yours originally but wasn't completely sure. I'll just turn the water back on then. Thanks!

Comment: When you replace it, accept that freezing is now normal in your area and install it in a way that it will either not be exposed to freezing, or can be drained quickly and with minimal effort before freezing weather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning off the valve that supplies the water to the backflow preventer isolates the water going into your home.  You're safe.

The BFP when functioning properly allows water to be fed to the sprinkler system, but prevents, (as the name states) that water from being forced back into the incoming potable water.

Since the valve was damaged by freeze, you turned it off and now everything downstream from that shutoff valve is isolated from the potable water.  Nothing to worry about.

You can potentially wait until warmer weather to repair/ replace the valve. The down side is no sprinkler system.